# How to set time on load in ajax

Tags: php, ajax

Here is my code customize.js:

```
$(document).on('click','#savescore',function(e){

    var x = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

    $('input[name="name[]"]').each(function(){

        var values = ($(this).val());

        var a = $(this).attr('data');

        $.ajax({

                 url:"http://www.csscorecard.com/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/ajax/submit.php?function=updateScore",

                 type:"post",

                 data:{ score:values , id:a },
                 success:function(data){
                }

            });

           })
           $('#alert-success').addClass('show-alert-csp');
           $(this).disabled = true;

           document.getElementById('editscore').disabled = false;

})
```

My problem is there are 50 data to loop in my input type,
I want to set a time into 5sec before the $('#alert-success').addClass('show-alert-csp'); appear to make all data save in database because everytime I update the data after I refresh the content not all data are updated. And i want to disable the cursor when time > 5sec.

Any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

you can use **setTimeout**

**Example**

```
setTimeout(function(){
 $('#alert-success').addClass('show-alert-csp');
},5000);  // 1 second = 1000
```

OR you can do it in after success ajax.

**Example**

```
success:function(data){
  $('#alert-success').addClass('show-alert-csp');
}
```

Comment: still no luck, when i tried that code the last data i updated didn`t update.

Comment: what response is coming in data ? we can use setInterval and check in every 5 second that all records is updated or not . if updated then addclass and clear interval. otherwise check until not updated all records

Comment: No response, the #alert-success didn`t add the class.

Comment: you need to do changes in php code . you should return only after all records updated.

Answer (score 0):

Setting a fixed time would not be a good solution. We are not sure if the process will indeed complete within the time you have set (what if the server fails, what if the server is slow). Instead, your AJAX request should return a response (upon successful insertion into the database, or failure to do so). Once the response is received, a callback function should be called on the client side to display the appropriate success / error message.

Assuming the server returns the appropriate response, you can have something like:

```
$.ajax({

                    url:"http://www.csscorecard.com/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/ajax/submit.php?function=updateScore",

                    type:"post",

                    data:{ score:values , id:a },
                    success:function(data){
                        $('#alert-success').addClass('show-alert-csp');
                    }

                });
```

Comment: i tried that one but, if there are 50 data saved in database, the $('#alert-success').addClass('show-alert-csp'); will also appear 50x.

Comment: Then in the success function, you should have a counter that counts how many responses it got. When it reaches 50, that's the time you display the message. :)